# Laravel 4 Authentication & Protected Route

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I have some problems with Laravel 4 authentication & protected route... my problem is it seems like I kept getting redirected back to the login page instead of proceeding into the admin page after inputting the correct credentials.

I have previously tested that authentication of login function in HomeController is working by changing the Auth::Attempt to return "Yes" if the login credentials are accurate.

So, I believe this could be the problem for protected route.

Hope that you will be able to help me to understand better. Thank you!

Below are my codes:

HomeController:

```
        public function postLogin()
    {
            $input = Input::all();

            $rules = array('email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required');

            $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);

            if($v->fails())
            {

                    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($v);

            } else { 


                    if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'))))
                    {

                            return Redirect::to('admin');

                    } else {

                            return Redirect::to('login');
                    }
            }
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@getIndex');});
```

Filters:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('login');
});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('admin');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

within the array being passed into the Auth::attempt change the associative index 'email' to 'username' and try that.

```
Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')));
```